# Cлучайное число от 1 до 10

Tags: случайные-числа, любой-язык

Как написать функцию, которая возвращает случайное число от 1 до 10,используя генератор случайных чисел, ограниченный диапазоном от 1 до 5? В принципе подойдёт любой язык, мне главное идеи.

Comment: Вопрос в том, **каким должно быть распределение** этих случайных чисел?

Comment: @Harry, в смысле, чтобы не повторялись?

Comment: Еще неплохо бы уточнить, имеющийся генератор выдает целые или вещественные числа.

Comment: В смысле, что `x+y` даст вам случайные числа от 1 до 10, только вот 1 там встречаться не будет, а 5 будет встречаться чаще, чем 10. Вы в курсе, что такое **распределение** случайных чисел? И да - генератор выдает числа целые или вещественные?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, до этого момента я думал только про целые числа, хотя сейчас задумался... Нет, всё равно целые

Comment: Банальное решение в лоб - генерим случайное число от 1 до 5, умножаем на два, затем опять генерим число от 1 до 5, если получилось 4 или 5, то уменьшаем на единицу результат, если получилось 3 то пробуем заново.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, не совсем понял, откуда такое решение взялось?

Comment: @Alex сам придумал =)

Comment: @Harry, ничего про распределение не сказано в задании

Comment: Тогда это бессмысленный вопрос. Просто возвращать значение 8 - это тоже случайное число от 1 до 10, просто с очень специфическим распределением...

Comment: Генерируем три раза, складываем, получается от 3 до 15. Минус 2, получается от 1 до 13. Если больше десяти, генерируете заново.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev равномерность будет не очень

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan это понятно ) . Про неё в вопросе ни слова, написано что главное идеи, а не равномерность )) . Да и не известно что за генератор такой, может там в самом генераторе равномерностью и не пахнет.

Comment: @Harry, ну вы же понимаете, что возвращать постоянно одно число, это не то, что нужно в этой задаче. Несмотря на то, что в условии задачи про распределение ничего не сказано, пусть будет равномерное. Что тогда предложите?

Comment: Уже предложил :)

Comment: Интересно найти процесс который из минимального количества случайных независимых чисел вида `1...5` делает максимальное количество случайных независимых вида `1...10`.

Answer (score 10):

Возможно, такой ответ уже дали, но не пропадать же добру.
P.S. Да, по сути у меня ответ совпадает с ответом Harry, долго я код писал.
P.P.S. В конце добавил ещё один годный вариант, которого вроде бы не было ещё в комментариях.

```
import random
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def random1_5():
    return random.randint(1,5)

def random1_10():
    while True:
        x = random1_5()
        if x <= 2:
            return random1_5()
        elif x <= 4:
            return random1_5() + 5

n = 1000
y = [random1_10() for _ in range(n)]
sns.countplot(y)
plt.title('random(1,5) -> random(1,10)')

y1 = [random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(n)]
plt.figure()
sns.countplot(y1)
plt.title('random(1,10)')
```

Кидаем кубик 1-5 первый раз, чтобы выбрать диапазон:

- если выпадает 1 или 2, то следующее кидание кубика выдаём как есть
- если выпадет 3 или 4, то выдаём следующее кидание кубика + 5
- если выпадает 5, то кидаем кубик заново

Проверим распределение такого генератора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для сравнения распределение встроенного `random` от 1 до 10:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если запускать код несколько раз, то видно, что распределение выходит вполне равномерное, хотя и сдвигается туда-сюда. Но перекосов нет.

**UPDATE:**

Ради интереса проверил также вариант от Pavel Grishaev со сложением рандомов, распределение получается неравномерное:

```
def random1_10():
    while True:
        x = random1_5() + random1_5() + random1_5() - 2
        if x <= 10:
            return x
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE2:**

Вроде нашёл ещё один более-менее равномерный вариант:

```
def random1_10():
    return sum(random1_5() for _ in range(10)) % 10 + 1
```

Суть: складываем результаты рандома(1,5) 10 раз, берём остаток от деления на 10 и прибавляем 1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Последний вариант хотя и на практике приемлем, математически имеет неровное распределение: 0.0855, 0.0882, 0.0955, 0.1045, 0.1118, 0.1145, 0.1118, 0.1045, 0.0955, 0.0882

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Вы занимаетесь статистикой? )  До сих пор не до конца понимаю, как считать такие вероятности. Но если на собеседовании заставят, то, конечно, придётся как-то считать ))

Comment: Не, не силен, просто перебрал в грязном цикле все варианты https://www.online-python.com/3nXGcyYQe9

Answer (score 6):

Считая, что генератор **равномерный** и нужно равномерное же распределение:

Получаем случайное число, пока оно не станет равным 1,2,4 или 5.
Получаем второе случайное число.

Если первое - 1 или 2, возвращаем второе; если 4 или 5 - второе, увеличенное на 5.

`r()` - ваш генератор от 1 до 5.

Генератор от 1 до 10:

```
int v() {

    int k;
    for(k = r(); k == 3; k = r());
    if (k < 3) return r(); else return 5+r();
}
```

Проверка - https://ideone.com/6m47cs

Comment: Кросево, плюс. Интересно, можно ли без цикла подбора.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Ну не придумал, как проще поделить 5 чисел пополам :)

Comment: а можно добавить в ответ, почему полученное распределение останется равномерным?

Comment: @Grundy Лучше в комментарий :) Потому что половина чисел равномерно распределены от 1 до 5, вторая половина - *ровно столько же* - от 6 до 10.

Comment: Эх, по сути у меня такой же ответ. Опоздал я пока код писал ))

Comment: [Умные дядьки](https://perso.math.u-pem.fr/kloeckner.benoit/papiers/DiceSimulation.pdf) (Lemma 3) говорят что не получится без подбора.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Не думал, что залез в такие сложные материи...  *"Честное слово, я и не подозревал, что вот уже более сорока лет говорю прозой. Большое вам спасибо, что сказали."* (с) "Мещанин во дворянстве" Мольера...

Answer (score 2):

Интересная мысль пришла мне в бессоннице.

10 значений - это 5 пар значений. Естественным образом приходит мысль, что генератор [1, 5] дает нам номер пары.
Далее требуется равновероятно выбрать, какое число из пары выдать. Т.е. к полученному ранее числу нужно прибавить 0 или 1 (50/50).
А вот для этого нам генератор уже не требуется, можно прибавлять 1 и 0 поочередно.

Предлагаю расчет по следующей формуле:
`r = (2 * r1_5() - 1) + fb()`

Левая часть - выбор пары.
`fb()` - периодическая прямоугольная функция.

**Тест на JavaScript:**

```js
const r1_5 = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
const fb = () => fb.v++ % 2;

fb.v = 0;

let histo = Array(12).fill(0);

for(let i = 0; i<1000000; i++)
{
    let r = (2 * r1_5() - 1) + fb();
    histo[r]++;
}

histo.forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

**UPD**

Я осознал, что хотя статистически распределение равномерное, сама последовательность вызывает беспокойство, потому что состоит из чередующихся четных и нечетных чисел.
Поэтому предлагаю усовершенствованный вариант, где функция `fb()` будет зависеть от результата генератора [1, 5], т.е. обретает черты псевдослучайности:

```js
const r1_5 = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
const fb = (r) => (fb.v += r) % 2;

fb.v = 0;

let histo = Array(12).fill(0);

for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
  let r0 = r1_5();
  let r = (2 * r0 - 1) + fb(r0);

  histo[r]++;
}

histo.forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

**UPD2**
Как правильно заметил @VladimirGamalyan, вероятности для четных/нечетных чередуются, и с таким генератором, если собрать статистику, можно играть с положительным матожиданием (вероятность угадать 60%).

Comment: Коллеги, если вы минус ставите, дайте хотя бы комментарий. Любопытно же, чем не устраивает решение. По моим тестам, этот подход даёт хорошую последовательность, по свойствам не хуже, чем задающий генератор, при этом r1_5() вычисляется только один раз.

Comment: Вероятности для четных/нечетных чередуются. Т.е. зная что выпало четное, можно сделать ставку на более вероятное нечетное.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Вы совершенно правы. Заслуженно. Пока что меня нельзя допускать до разработки игровых автоматов. Спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам надо получить число от 1 до 10, генерируя числа в пределах от 1 до 5, то просто умножайте исходное число на 2 случайным образом:

Python

```
import random

num = random.randint(1,5)
double = random.randint(1,2)
print(double * num)
```

*UPD*

Если нельзя генерировать число от 1 до 2, то чтобы решить умножать или нет, то генерируем еще одно число от 1 до 5, если оно больше или равно 3, то умножаем на 2, иначе - нет. Тут правда с вероятностью 3/5 - будет умножать, 2/5 - не будет.

```
import random

num = random.randint(1,5)
double = 2 if random.randint(1,5) >=3 else 1
print(double * num)
```

Можно использовать сделать еще более псевдослучайную генерацию, привяжемся ко времени, если абсолютное время четное, то умножаем, иначе - нет.

Правда вроде генератор случайных числе тоже как-то привязан ко времени, не знаю какой это окажет эффект

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
num = random.randint(1,5)
double = 2 if datetime.now().microsecond % 2 == 0 else 1
print(double * num)
```

Правда у всех решений выше есть один важный недостаток, таким способом нельзя получить ни 7, ни 9. Спасибо @andreymel за наблюдение.

Можно ничего не умножать, а сгенерировать 2 числа и сложить случайным образом.

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
num = random.randint(1,5)
if datetime.now().microsecond % 2 == 0:
  print(num + random.randint(1,5))
else:
  print(num)
```

Comment: `random.randint(1,5)` - *генерирует число в диапазоне от 0 до 20*?! 8-0

Comment: числа поправила внутри по вопросу, а коммент поправить забыла, спасибо xD

Comment: Вроде автору нужно от 1 до 10

Comment: `Math.random( )` генерирует числа от 1 до 5? 8-0

Comment: По условию генератор дает целые числа от 1 до 5 (нельзя использовать рандом от 1 до 2).

Comment: Такой код даёт очень плохое распределение чисел, и в нём никогда не выпадают 7 и 9. Тест на 100000 случайных числах: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAdRQ.png

Comment: Обновлённый код даёт немного другое распределение, но в нём всё ещё нет чисел 7 и 9 https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcznL.png

Comment: Да, там никогда и не выпадут ни 7, 9, т.к. их нельзя получить умножением на 2, тут только случайным образом прибавлять или выичтать 1, но слишком много генерировать, хорошо или плохо - не знаю. Спасибо, сейчас подучаю как улучшить

Comment: Просто пятерку прибавлять или нет, как у Гарри

Comment: Да, или так, спасибо)

Comment: Снова обновлённый код даёт треугольно-сломанное распределение https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rocS.png (и я не уверен, что по условиям задачи можно использовать текущее время)

Answer (score -1):

Сложить 25 случайных чисел от 0 до 4, взять остаток от деления на 10, прибавить единицу:

```kotlin
fun random10(): Int {
    var sum = 0
    repeat(25) {
        sum += random5() - 1
    }
    return sum % 10 + 1
}
```

Распределение для 1 000 000 случайных значений:

[image: распределение случайной величины]

[0.1003, 0.0996, 0.0998, 0.0999, 0.0997, 0.1002, 0.1000, 0.1001, 0.1001, 0.1002]

Comment: А почему именно 25, а не, скажем, 20 или 100?

Comment: Интуитивно, чтобы получилось равномерное распределение.